# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: instance exception using yuicompressor to minify JS files

Tags: java, ant, minify

We are in the process of upgrading out application servers from Weblogic 11g running java 1.6 to Weblogic 12c running java 1.8.  One of the steps in our ANT build process is to use YUI Compressor (version 2.4.8) to minify our CSS and JS files.  The step to minify CSS files works fine.  But when we try to minify JS files we get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: instance
    at org.mozilla.javascript.CompilerEnvirons.<init>(CompilerEnvirons.java:48)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.parse(JavaScriptCompressor.java:310)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.<init>(JavaScriptCompressor.java:533)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressTask.doCompression(YUICompressTask.java:202)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressTask.execute(YUICompressTask.java:101)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
```

When I looked into the classes inside **yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar** causing the error I see that line 48 of CompilerEnvirons.java looks like this:

```
this.errorReporter = DefaultErrorReporter.instance;
```

But when I checked the class DefaultErrorReporter.java it's empty.  The entire class consists of the following:

```
class 
{
}
```

Java 1.6 didn't seem to care about this but java 1.8 does.

I'm not an expert with this compressor tool by any means so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on what might cause this.  If I need to provide additional information I'm happy to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a corrupt JAR file.